# Read a remote XML file or copy it to locale (using Java)?

Tags: java, xml, performance

My question is about reading a remote XML file by using Java.
My files are stored in one device that runs Windows CE. I should access to few of these devices several times per day.
Which solution is more efficient considering network constraints, stablishment of a TCP session and data loss: to open and read the file remotelly or get a copy locally to the server and process it then?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems u want the files to be read from client by server, whereas it most cases its the other way round. In this case you should have some push functionality from the client to server and this can be over HTTP.

Or you can have a Http connection listener running in the client which accepts request from server and sends back the XML file to the server. Essentially its like a server thread running in the client.

Not sure if u running JAVA on Windows CE. Look for solutions in Windows CE HTTP listener.

See if it helps

Comment: Yes I think it is a good solution. The fact is that I had the idea to schedule the job of getting data in an application running in the server. Then I would get the data using sockets or maybe web services. What do you think about this approach? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Ideally yes, in a scenario where u want some task to be done on a regular interval, you should have a scheduler or cronjob for this task.